# Unable to upload files through File Upload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i am trying to upload files through the ASP.NET File Upload control.
Every thing is working fine, except for the fact that when i try to upload the file on the server i am getting an error: (probably some authorization exception).

do i need to give some rights to the upload up there on the server. If so then for which account and do i need to restart the server after giving rights??

Please help...

thank you

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Please post the full exception stack trace.

Comment: Just to make sure, I suggest you upload small files for your testing (nothing larger than 4K), since there's an upload limit size by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Network Service` (in security) and give all full control for the folder to which you are uploading the file. if still it doesn't work then add `Everyone` and give full control.

Comment: giving Network Service all rights resolved the problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try add modify rights on the folder to the network and network services user